# How to sum array objects become a object?

Tags: javascript

I have a question for this case

Input:

```
data = [
{ number_1: 10, number_2: 20 },
{ number_1: 15, number_2: 5 },
{ number_1: 15, number_2: 35 },
];
```

Output:

```
dataSum = { sum_number_1: 40, sum_number_2: 60 };
```

I want to ask for 2 method we can use: **array.reduce** and **array.forEach**. And I see we need to transform array to an object for output. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: *"I want to ask for 2 method we can use: array.reduce and array.forEach."* Don't use `reduce` for this, it overcomplicates things. (In general, if you're not doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions, don't use `reduce`.) You'll see `reduce` used a lot, almost always where the code would be simpler and clearer with a loop. I also wouldn't use `forEach`, I'd use a `for-of` loop, but `forEach` can work as well.

Comment: Basically: Create a result object with those two properties and the values `0`. Loop through the array adding the property values from each object to the values in your result object.

Comment: Looks like an assignment/exercise to me :( Just try to do it and show what you have done. Otherwise, SE is the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial schema for `Array.reduce` is really up to you.

```js
const data = [{
    number_1: 10,
    number_2: 20
  },
  {
    number_1: 15,
    number_2: 5
  },
  {
    number_1: 15,
    number_2: 35
  },
];

const res = data.reduce((acc, {
  number_1,
  number_2
}) => {
  acc.sum_number_1 += number_1;
  acc.sum_number_2 += number_2;

  return acc;
}, {
  sum_number_1: 0,
  sum_number_2: 0
})

console.log(res)
```

And here's `forEach`

```js
const data = [{
    number_1: 10,
    number_2: 20
  },
  {
    number_1: 15,
    number_2: 5
  },
  {
    number_1: 15,
    number_2: 35
  },
];

const res = {
  sum_number_1: 0,
  sum_number_2: 0
};

data.forEach(({
  number_1,
  number_2
}) => {
  res.sum_number_1 += number_1;
  res.sum_number_2 += number_2;
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```js
data.reduce((acc, {number_1, number_2}) => {
    acc.sum_number_1 += number_1;
    acc.sum_number_2 += number_2;
    return acc;
},{sum_number_1: 0, sum_number_2: 0})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```js
data = [
   { number_1: 10, number_2: 20 },
   { number_1: 15, number_2: 5 },
   { number_1: 15, number_2: 35 },
];

const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator.sum_number_1 += currentValue.number_1;
  accumulator.sum_number_2 += currentValue.number_2;
  return accumulator;
};

console.log(data.reduce(reducer, { sum_number_1: 0, sum_number_2: 0 }));
```

The [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function is used with an initial value structured as the final object to be returned. The numbers are summed in the callback function to then return the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a dynamic approach which sums all properties of an object.

```js
const
    data = [{ number_1: 10, number_2: 20 }, { number_1: 15, number_2: 5 }, { number_1: 15, number_2: 35 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + v)
        return r;
    });

console.log(result);
```